# QGIS 3 Unmet dependencies on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, qgis-3

My QGIS 3 (2.99, Ubuntu 16.04) stopped upgrading today. When doing `sudo apt-get upgrade`, I get an error about `Unmet dependencies`.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 qgis-plugin-grass : Depends: qgis-provider-grass (= 1:2.99.0+git20171211+61db97f+24xenial-ubuntugis) but 1:2.99.0+git20171209+fb28adf+24xenial-ubuntugis is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Doing

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
```

as suggested, I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libqt5script5
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  qgis-provider-grass
The following packages will be upgraded:
  qgis-provider-grass
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
22 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2,068 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 


(Reading database ... 286420 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../qgis-provider-grass_1%3a2.99.0+git20171211+61db97f+24xenial-ubuntugis_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking qgis-provider-grass (1:2.99.0+git20171211+61db97f+24xenial-ubuntugis) over (1:2.99.0+git20171209+fb28adf+24xenial-ubuntugis) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/qgis-provider-grass_1%3a2.99.0+git20171211+61db97f+24xenial-ubuntugis_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/qgis/plugins/libgrassprovider7.so' to '/usr/lib/qgis/plugins/libgrassprovider7.so.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/qgis-provider-grass_1%3a2.99.0+git20171211+61db97f+24xenial-ubuntugis_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I use the following repositories in my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu xenial main
deb http://qgis.org/ubuntugis-nightly xenial main
```

So far, `apt-get` is broken and keeps asking me to do `apt-get -f install` no matter what (`autoremove`, `autoclean`, `clean` etc.).

Does anyone have similar experience or know of a fix?

Comment: Looks like a packaging or download error of qgis-provider-grass. Try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` or remove or purge the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Post is related to a rapidly changing event.

I guess the solution is to wait a day or two. I tried `sudo apt-get upgrade` again, and it succeeded.