# Installing QGIS3 on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial: dependency problem

Tags: qgis-3

I am trying to install QGIS3 on my Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial.

Following the instructions on the [QGIS Website](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html) I added the following lines to my sources.list:

```
deb https://qgis.org/ubuntugis xenial main
deb-src https://qgis.org/ubuntugis xenial main
```

I run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and try to execute the installation:

```
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

For each of the packages I get the answer that there are several missing packages:

```
python-qgis : Depends: python-qgis-common (= 1:3.0.0+24xenial-ubuntugis) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libqgispython3.0.0 but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libqgis-analysis3.0.0 but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libqgis-core3.0.0 but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libqgis-gui3.0.0 but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libqgis-server3.0.0 but it is not going to be installed
 qgis : Depends: gdal-abi-2-2-2 but it is not installable
    Depends: libgdal20 (>= 1.8.0) but it is not installable
    Depends: libqgis-analysis3.0.0 but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: libqgis-app3.0.0 but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: libqgis-core3.0.0 but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: libqgis-gui3.0.0 but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: qgis-providers (= 1:3.0.0+24xenial-ubuntugis) but it is not going to be installed
 qgis-plugin-grass : Depends: qgis-provider-grass (= 1:3.0.0+24xenial-ubuntugis) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libgdal20 (>= 1.8.0) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libqgis-app3.0.0 but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libqgis-core3.0.0 but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libqgis-gui3.0.0 but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libqgisgrass7-3.0.0 but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: grass740 but it is not installable
```

Most interesting is that some packages are **not installable: gdal-abi-2-2-2, libgdal20, grass740**

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/265146/qgis-3-unmet-dependencies-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: If you don't have LTS xenial version I think that QGIS 3 is not installable because your Ubuntu is too old. Read this note: https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#id9

Answer (score 11):

**Tested 29/06/2018**

```
--QGIS 3 Ubuntu 16.04

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://qgis.org/ubuntugis  xenial main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb-src https://qgis.org/ubuntugis xenial main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable

wget -O - https://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2017.gpg.key | gpg --import
gpg --fingerprint CAEB3DC3BDF7FB45
gpg --export --armor CAEB3DC3BDF7FB45 | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

Comment: do I have to uninstall my previous version for this first and just this code would work or do I have to add more (not a pro in ubuntu)

Comment: Is repeated "sudo apt-get update" useful or necessary?

Comment: For me, on my Ubuntu 16.04 following this instructions installs QGIS 2.18.16.

Comment: These commands installed QGIS 3.4 successfully, but there is not Qt Designer.

Answer (score 5):

For QGIS3 on xenial you have to use ubuntugis-unstable ppa

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable

Comment: Indeed that worked for me today, they should probably update QGIS Installer docs

Comment: @adamczi I think https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#id10 is clear enough.

Comment: you're right @AndreJ, I must have read it incorrectly or maybe it changed. I'd also like to point out that `universe` was needed to be enabled on my Ubuntus to make it work (otherwise I got a lot of 'not going to be installed' stuff)

Comment: I guess you would not be able to install any software if you kicked off the main ubuntu repository. Unless you try to self-compile everything...

Answer (score 1):

If you have conda, you can do:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda create -n qgis3 -c ceholden -c QuantStack qgis=3
source activate qgis3
qgis
```

Source: https://github.com/conda-forge/qgis-feedstock/issues/17#issuecomment-373871708

Comment: You **can** use conda, but it is not necessary for installing QGIS3.

Comment: See my previous answer. I was not meaning to say that it is absolutely necessary, but for this answer it is.

Answer (score 0):

`#/etc/source.list.d/ubuntugis.list
deb https://qgis.org/ubuntugis xenial main
deb-src https://qgis.org/ubuntugis xenial main`

and

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install qgis`

is what my colleague seems to have found out.

Before that, I managed to install it by manually downloading all dependency *.deb files from https://qgis.org/ubuntugis/pool/main/q/qgis/
and installing them with gdebi.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install QGis 3.4 on Ubuntu 16.04 by removing the libsqlite3.so.0 symbolic link

```
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.0
```

Answer (score -1):

I have Linux Mint 18.3 (Ubuntu 16.04 ) computer, I followed the following aforementioned guidelines:

```
--QGIS 3 Ubuntu 16.04

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://qgis.org/ubuntugis  xenial main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb-src https://qgis.org/ubuntugis xenial main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable

wget -O - https://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2017.gpg.key | gpg --import
gpg --fingerprint CAEB3DC3BDF7FB45
gpg --export --armor CAEB3DC3BDF7FB45 | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

However I was still getting unmanaged dependency errors. Hence I tried with aptitude as follows:

sudo aptitude install qgis python-qgis

To resolve the dependency I selected :

```
 Install the following packages:                         
1)    python3-psycopg2 [2.7.6.1-3.pgdg16.04+1 (xenial-pgdg)]
```

and accepted the proposed solution. After the package manager installed all of the qgis libraries, I could observe qgis 3.4.4 Maedira on my screen with joy.