# How to install qgis 3 on unbuntu 16.04

Tags: installation, ubuntu, qgis-3

I've followed the instructions from this question [Installing QGIS3 on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial: dependency problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276539/installing-qgis3-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-dependency-problem)

I tried all the possible repositories but It keeps installing the 2.18 version.

Can anyone explain me how to install qgis3 on ubuntu 16.04 please?

Comment: You can comment or add a bounty to the existing question if you would like to encourage more (or different) answers. The locations in that question work for me on 16.04.

Comment: As i said following the given instrucions it keeps installing the 2.18 so it is not a duplicate!

Comment: From what I see that question has no answered answer. You may comment under existing answers and describe what went wrong.

Comment: @IanTurton Suggesting bounty to newbie is not really helpful, there is a minimum point count to use it.

Comment: @Mattia check https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/287948/49538 ,tested now.