# UBUNTU 16.04, QGIS 3.4 above Installation problem

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-2

I want to **install QGIS 3.4 above** and did exactly the same as this page:
[QGIS Installers](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html)

and tried the codes below having no error at all:

(1) add the following lines to `/etc/apt/sources.list`

`deb https://qgis.org/ubuntu xenial main`

`deb-src https://qgis.org/ubuntu xenial main`

(2) `wget -O - https://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2017.gpg.key | gpg --import`

`gpg --fingerprint CAEB3DC3BDF7FB45` which gives the results below:

*pub   2048R/BDF7FB45 2017-08-16 [expires: 2019-08-16]
      Key fingerprint = 61E0 A086 749E 463E DE50  2255 CAEB 3DC3 BDF7 FB45
uid                  QGIS Archive Automatic Signing Key (2017) 
sub   2048R/E959BBCF 2017-08-16 [expires: 2019-08-16]*

then:

`gpg --export --armor CAEB3DC3BDF7FB45 | sudo apt-key add -`

at last:

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key CAEB3DC3BDF7FB45`

(3) `sudo apt-get update`

(4) `sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass`

**every thing goes fine except that these codes installs only QGIS 2.18 but not 3.4 above?**

**I have tried other repositories as well and it still goes the same and installs QGIS 2.18**

I need a solution and I need this software on my Ubuntu.

Regards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276539/installing-qgis3-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-dependency-problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you follow the instructions from the [QGIS Installers](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu) page, you will see the following information under the "*Supported distribution versions:*" table:

> Ubuntu    16.04 (LTS) xenial [5]
>   ...
>
> [5]   3.0 and above only available with ubuntugis-unstable (plain xenial lacks GDAL2)

[image]

So, add the ubuntugis-unstable ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
```

Then use the "*Release with ubuntugis-unstable dependencies*" repository (https://qgis.org/ubuntugis) in your /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb https://qgis.org/ubuntugis xenial main
deb-src https://qgis.org/ubuntugis xenial main
```

You should then be able to install QGIS 3.4.2 according to the [packages list](https://qgis.org/ubuntugis/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages):

```
Package: qgis
Version: 1:3.4.2+24xenial-ubuntugis
Architecture: amd64
Maintainer: QGIS developers <qgis-developer@lists.osgeo.org>
Installed-Size: 9720
Depends: gdal-abi-2-2-2, libc6 (>= 2.14), libgcc1 (>= 1:3.0), libgdal20 (>= 1.8.0), libgeos-c1v5 (>= 3.4.2), libgsl2, libqgis-analysis3.4.2, libqgis-app3.4.2, libqgis-core3.4.2, libqgis-gui3.4.2, libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0), libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) | libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2), libqt5keychain0 (>= 0.3.0), libqt5network5 (>= 5.0.2), libqt5sql5 (>= 5.0.2), libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.2.0), libqt5xml5 (>= 5.0.2), libstdc++6 (>= 5.2), ocl-icd-libopencl1 | libopencl1, ocl-icd-libopencl1 (>= 1.0) | libopencl-1.1-1, python-qgis (= 1:3.4.2+24xenial-ubuntugis), qgis-providers (= 1:3.4.2+24xenial-ubuntugis), qgis-common (= 1:3.4.2+24xenial-ubuntugis)
Recommends: qgis-plugin-grass
Suggests: gpsbabel
Conflicts: uim-qt3
Homepage: http://qgis.org/
Priority: optional
Section: science
Filename: pool/main/q/qgis/qgis_3.4.2+24xenial-ubuntugis_amd64.deb
Size: 6675744
SHA256: ac91806eb635de040e33b8178b340a2d0a604be9f0efad804b06b024a27c1f1e
SHA1: 1d08b3f07c7323f937a0fc4c0eb53327a655de4e
MD5sum: 3a584cde9314eace49e651a197197a2f
Description: Geographic Information System (GIS)
 A Geographic Information System (GIS) manages, analyzes, and displays
 databases of geographic information. QGIS supports shape file viewing and
 editing, spatial data storage with PostgreSQL/PostGIS, projection on-the-fly,
 map composition, and a number of other features via a plugin interface. QGIS
 also supports display of various georeferenced raster and Digital Elevation
 Model (DEM) formats including GeoTIFF, Arc/Info ASCII Grid, and USGS ASCII
 DEM.
```

Comment: It might be necessary to add the ubuntugis key as well. Before installing, use `sudo apt-cache policy qgis` to see what is available for you.

Comment: @AndreJ possible, but unlikely as `add-apt-repository` by default adds the key.

Comment: @Luke It worked perfectly. thank you for your great details. Regards