# Installation of QGIS 3.4.4 on Ubuntu 16.04 fails to install qgis-plugin-grass because of uninstallable grass760 dependency

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, ubuntu, ubuntugis

I have used the instructions  [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276539/installing-qgis3-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-dependency-problem/287948) marked **Tested 29/06/2018** to install QGIS 3.4.4 on Ubuntu 16.04.  While QGIS installs nicely I get an error on installing qgis-plugin-grass.  Subsequently the Grass tools listed in the processing window all throw errors.

Upon installation I get the following error...

```
The following packages have unmet dependencie: qgis-plugin-grass :
Depends; grass760 but it is not installable.  
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried reinstalling using aptitude but this did not make any difference.  How do I install the grass760 dependencies and qgis-plugin-grass?

Comment: Can you try again? Meanwhile GRASS GIS 7.8.0 with Python 3 support has been made available, also for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If you stick to the ubuntugis-unstable ppa (with nothing from qgis.org in your sources list), you should be able to install QGIS 3.4.6 solely from the ppa.

BTW QGIS 3.4.4 is not the latest QGIS-ltr version; I wonder where you have that from. Maybe you should run `apt-cache policy qgis` to see what is available for you.

Comment: Should I purge QGIS and paths to the repositories and just install using these commands then?                                                                                                    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo  sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass

Comment: Yes, go ahead. And keep an eye on any error messages.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36879592/has-anyone-got-qgis-to-install-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts